# Dependencies of programs using gtk/gtk.h

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gtk, dependencies, cairo

I have mini pc with vortex86DX processor. And today I install Ubuntu 9.04 on it. Now I want to use my program, which use gtk/gtk.h, to display some data. And I have question - 
What dependencies have programs, which use GTK 3.0? It's very important for me, because I have not internet access on this small pc.

Comment: What is your GTK application doing? Explain more!

Comment: I plot graphics using cairo, zoom out/in, some math operations and etc. Thank you for answer. And I have another question: Can I compile code of my program on development workstation and after run it from small pc?

Comment: You can compile on development PC and run on the small PC. If both development & target linux distributions are same, don't bother. Otherwise, consider chroot-ing the target distribution on the devlopment PC. And please accept or upvote my answer if it fits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally build such GTK programs using [pkg-config](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/). And I am getting (on Debian/Sid/AMD64) the compile flags

```
  % pkg-config --cflags gtk+-x11-3.0
  -pthread -I/usr/include/gtk-3.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 \
  -I/usr/include/at-spi2-atk/2.0 -I/usr/include/pango-1.0 \
  -I/usr/include/gio-unix-2.0/ -I/usr/include/cairo \
  -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 \
  -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include \
  -I/usr/include/harfbuzz -I/usr/include/freetype2 \
  -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/libpng12 \
  -I/usr/include/libdrm
```

and the link flags

```
   % pkg-config --libs gtk+-x11-3.0
  -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -latk-1.0 -lgio-2.0 -lpangocairo-1.0 \
  -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lcairo-gobject -lpango-1.0 -lcairo \
  -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0
```

Notice that these shared libraries link some other ones (eg `-lX11` or `-ldbus`). Try to `ldd` some GTK binary (e.g. your own one, or `gedit`)

<sup>NB: I have manually added the backslashes and newlines for readability</sup>

However, there are much more other runtime dependencies: the X11 server and related things (session and windows managers, fonts and images notably and perhaps even some "desktop" environment à la Gnome or IceWM, etc...).

I suggest installing GTK usig the package system (e.g. using `aptitude install` on Ubuntu) with a network connection (perhaps using a chroot-ed environment) to understand all the dependencies.